# How to group count and join in sequel?

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

I've looked through all the documentation and I'm having an issue putting together this query in Sequel.

```
select a.*, IFNULL(b.cnt, 0) as cnt FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN (select a_id, count(*) as cnt from b group by a_id) as b ON b.a_id = a.id ORDER BY cnt
```

Think of table A as products and table B is a record indicated A was purchased.

So far I have:

```
A.left_outer_join(B.group_and_count(:a_id), a_id: :id).order(:count)
```

Essentially I just want to group and count table B, join it with A, but since B does not necessarily have any records for A and I'm ordering it by the number in B, I need to default a value.

Comment: You can order it by this: IFNULL(b.cnt, 0)

Comment: Hi guys, I have the correct sql, what I need help with is the Sequel equivalent (a ruby ORM like ActiveRecord).

Comment: Ah, I thought sequel was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DB[:a].
  left_outer_join(DB[:b].group_and_count(:a_id).as(:b), :a_id=>:id).
  order(:cnt).
  select_all(:a).
  select_more{IFNULL(:b__cnt, 0).as(:cnt)}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks Jeremy!  I didn't notice IFNULL in any of the sequel documentation, is that part of Sequel's query DSL or directly to MySQL (I may not understand how the {} expression blocks are evaluated)

Comment: The {} expression blocks are virtual row blocks, see http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/virtual_rows_rdoc.html for details.

Answer (score -2):

I can help you in MS SQL syntax.

Let's say your tables are Product and Order.

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
  Id INT NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [Order] (
  Id INT NOT NULL,
  ProductId INT)

INSERT INTO Product (Id, Name) VALUES
(1, 'Tea'), (2, 'Coffee'), (3, 'Hot Chocolate')

INSERT INTO [Order] (Id, ProductId) VALUES
(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2)
```

This query will give the number of orders each product has, including ones without any orders.

```
SELECT p.Id AS ProductId,
       p.Name AS ProductName,
       COUNT(o.Id) AS Orders
FROM Product p 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN [Order] o
           ON p.Id = o.ProductId
GROUP BY
       p.Id,
       p.Name
ORDER BY
       COUNT(o.Id) DESC
```

Comment: I think the question is about the syntax required by Ruby Sequel, a database toolkit.